# LibreOffice export compatibility with .doc

Tags: libreoffice, file-format

I know I can open `.doc` files in LibreOffice, but can I save a new document as a `.doc`? You used to be able to do so in OpenOffice, but I can't find anything in LibreOffice to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can do this easily using **Save as**:

Go to File--> Save as .

[image]

And there is even support for `.docx`.

> LibreOffice Writer is capable of opening and saving documents in a number of formats, including the OASIS Open Document Format 1.1 (its default format), Microsoft Word's DOC, DOCX, RTF and XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select **File->Save as**

The more intuitive **File-> Export** does **not** provide the option to select the file type.

[I lost hours trying to find out why I could not choose the file type when trying to export...]