# How to produce a MSWord like document on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: libreoffice, conversion, abiword

I made a very important document using Puppy 5.1 with AbiWord. Next I was to copy it on another PC using Ubuntu 11.10. I opened it easily & worked on it with LibreOffice Writer. My document is ready & I must in few hours print it via PC not serving Linux text editors = I must convert it into MSWord like format. Please, young friends, help me explaining me old 63 years old man what should I do to finish my work?

Comment: What format does this MCWord use, or do you mean Microsoft Word.

Comment: If you want the document to look the same as you see it and there is no need for the recipient to change it, go for PDF as output format.

Comment: When you've opened a file in LibreOffice, click on **File, Save As**. In the window that opens, near the bottom right, click on **All Formats**. Choose an appropriate **MS Office** version such as `Microsoft Word '97/2000/XP/2003`: don't go for `.docx` unless it's absolutely needed; just go with `.doc`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/51412/44179

Answer (score 0):

Unless some other person needs to edit the document, create a PDF version and print that. In LibreOffice Writer: File / Export as PDF ... / Export.

Comment: THANK U VERY MUCH! U're both great! 2 aswers were correct, but I fixed it on a little other way = I foud in my PC old MCWord doc., copied the text of AbiWord one there & made new mc mode printable!